# Reading emails using Java on Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an Android application that can read all the emails (including the unread and read ones) and store it in an array variable. Please help as I am not able to get any answer.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.  There are lots of StackOverflow Q&As on reading and sending emails from android.  And tutorials.  And youtube videos.

Comment: For example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_overview.htm

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.